# Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in PasswordResetsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

With this configuration on development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
  :host => 'localhost',
  :port => '3000'
 }
# Options: :smtp, :test

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address => 'smtp.gmail.com',
:port => 587,
:domain => 'gmail.com',
:user_name => 'mymail@mail.com',
:password => 'secret',
:authentication => :plain,
:enable_starttls_auto => true }
```

it raises the error (despite of the email was sent according the log)
 Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in PasswordResetsController#create 
 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. vm8sm19195643wjc.27 - gsmtp

Answer (score 0):

Copy the script in config/environments/development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
:port                 => 587,
:user_name            => 'giveyourvalidgmailaccount@gmail.com',
:password             => 'valid password of this gmail account',
:authentication       => 'plain',
:enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Replace user_name and password with valid gmail account. It will work.